# While parsing into a root folder how can I distinguish the upcoming is whether a file or a folder in C language?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to parse through a root folder which is entered by the user by using multi threading and multi processing at different versions.But how can I distinguish while I am parsing through a root folder whether the next is a folder or a file?To summarize I want to learn how I can distinguish the upcoming is a file or a folder.I wanna learn this because if it is a folder then I let opening this folder to a dynamically thread and/or process.If it is a file the existing thread or process can continue its work without any necessarity to create any different thread and/or process.I hope I can express my problem.I am waiting your answers.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a path refers to a file or directory using the [`stat()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html), and checking the `st_mode` field on the returned structure (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html).

On Windows, you can use [`GetFileAttributesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the file attributes, which you can check to see if it is a file or a directory.

Note that whatever you use may be subject to a race condition if the file system is being updated by another thread or process at the same time, as the file/directory may be deleted and/or changed after you checked it and before you access it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some quick samples. It will be up to you to thread from multiple root locations, call these recursively, and sync all the data.

Under *nix systems;

```
struct dirent *entry;
while ((entry = readdir("/root")) != NULL)
{
   if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
   {
      // do something
   }
}
closedir(dir);
```

Under Windows:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(("C:\\root" + "*.*").c_str(), &findData);
do
{
   if (findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
   {
      // do something
   }

} while (FindNextFile(hFind, &findData));

FindClose(hFind);
```